# What is the difference between DocumentRoot and PassengerAppRoot in this code?

Tags: node.js, cpanel, passenger, phusion

```
DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html
PassengerStartupFile index.js
PassengerAppType node
PassengerAppRoot /home/user/nodeapp
```

This how you set up the startup file of the cpanel application manager. I don´t understand the difference and this is my main problem to make it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocumentRoot is related to the directory where your domain is pointing  if you are using cpanel there is high chance is public_html.`DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html`, passenger AppRoot is where your app is located could be public_html or another route, that´s depend totally of you, a good hint is your application manager configuration in cpanel, it´s the same folder you setup, and user in the example is your user cpanel name.
If you change the code in this way and still is not working, I suggest contact technical support.